# Make header smaller when not-homepage opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this website; http://kieronboz.co.uk/inspired/

Im a beginner to web design, so forgive me :P

If you click on the top link in the ugly navigation bar on the left, a new page is loaded, I thought it might be a good idea to now shrink the header image for the non-main pages, so I was thinking a jquery script to make it 'slide' up when the page is loaded, to the top of the light white border around Inspired Marketing, so it would turn into a smaller header!

Anyway, problem is I cant find anything like this in google, I have seen the jquery slideup function but im having trouble implementing it in such a naked fashion as the code reference sheets present it.

If this is a terrible idea and there's better options, ill hear those too! Thanks again

Comment: Is that a one page solution, or will the links to own pages?

Comment: Hi @SvenBieder all of the currently inactive pages will be active and require the implementation too, I understand this may complicate it? So i am prepared to abandon the idea lol.

Comment: No, that's not complicated. But when every link goes to an own sub-page, there is no need for javascript to resize the header at all. You just make the header on the certain pages in the size you want it.

Comment: Im not sure why I didn't think of that as the solution, though I wont be able to animate it going up this way will I haha. Thanks though!

Comment: I made the mistake of translating that page. Aw, my poor brain cells.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add to the header the `margin-top: -540px;` (or via jquery: `$("#header").css("marginTop","-540px");`

You may use jquery.animate to add an animation to it.

As to doing it only on pages that are not the index - Either include the script doing it only to non-index pages, or use document.location.href to figure out whether you're on index or not.

Comment: Hi there, ill have a look at this, is the animate an easy addition? Googling now anyway! Thanks

Comment: As easy as $("#header").animate({
    marginTop: -540
  }, 250, function() {
    // animation complete callback
  });

Comment: Hey @user2584113 I have attempted to add it, and as you can imagine I have done it wrong haha. The image has been affected somehow; http://kieronboz.co.uk/inspired/equibright.html but I cannot pinpoint what exactly is happening myself.

Comment: Please notice two things - You don't have jquery on page (your source refer to 404, fix your script include), and you have a comment inline (// animation complete), you may remove all the function() { // animation complete callback } or replace the "//animation complete callback" with ";".